# Can Not Use SSIS for Oracle

Tags: ssis, etl

I install the VS 2019 and SSDT after that SQL SERVER 2019 Dev Edition.

> [Oracle Destination [223]] Error: The SSIS runtime version 15.0.2000.5
> is too low for this Oracle connector. Please install a newer version
> of SSIS (later than SQL Server 2019 RTM).

Answer (score 1):

if you are running in Visual Studio by default it will run in 32bit mode because Visual Studio is 32bit. If you also have SQL Server 2019 installed on the same machine then you can run in 64bit mode. You mentioned that you downloaded the 64bit connector, so I suppose you are running the package in 64bit mode, in which case it will launch the package with SSIS bits that came from the SQL Server 2019 installation.

The version 15.0.2070.41 is the RTM version of SQL Server 2019. For the Oracle connector to work properly, it requires at least the CU1 (cumulative update) version of SQL Server 2019 to be installed. The latest one is already CU4 now. **S**ee https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4548597/cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2019. Please upgrade your SQL Server installation to CU4 and try again.****

After Upgrade, all worked fine!